# How can I solve a Bessel equation with Reduction of order?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian, reduction-of-order-ode

If $y_{1}(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt(x)}$ is one solution of the differential equation $$x^2y'' +xy' + (x^2-\frac{1}{4})y = 0$$
find the second solution $y_{2}(x)$.

**My effort using Wronskian**

The general form of the homogeneous linear 2nd order differential equation is :

$$  y'' + p(x)y' +q(x)y =0$$

The given differential eqaution is a Bessel equation with $n =\frac{1}{4}$ :

$$x^2 y'' +xy' + (x^2 - \frac{1}{4})y = 0$$

Rearranging :

\begin{align*} 
x^2 y'' +xy' + (x^2 =\frac{1}{4})y = 0 \\ 
 y'' +\frac{x}{x^2}y' + \frac{(x^2 -\frac{1}{4})}{x^2}y = 0 \\
  y'' +\frac{x}{x^2}y' + \frac{(x^2 -\frac{1}{4})}{x^2}y = 0 \\
   y'' +\frac{1}{x}y' + (1 - \frac{\frac{1}{4}}{x^2}) y = 0 \\
      y'' +\frac{1}{x}y' + (1 - \frac{1}{4x^2}) y = 0 \\
\end{align*}

Therefore $$p(x) = \frac{1}{x}$$

Using Abel's Theorem we have :

$$y_{2}(x) = y_{1}(x) \int \left( \frac{ e^{-\int p(x)dx}}{ y_{1}^2(x)} \right) dx$$

Substituting :
$$\begin{align*} 
y_{2}(x) &= \frac{sin(x)}{\sqrt(x)} \int \left( \frac{ e^{-\int \frac{1}{x}dx}}{ \left(\frac{sin(x)}{\sqrt(x)}\right)^2} \right) dx \\ 
&= \frac{sin(x)}{\sqrt(x)} \int \left( \frac{ e^{-log(|x|)}}{ \left(\frac{sin^2(x)}{\sqrt(x)^2}\right)} \right) dx \\ 
&= \frac{sin(x)}{\sqrt(x)} \int \left( \frac{ |x|}{ \left(\frac{sin^2(x)}{x}\right)} \right) dx \\ 
&= \frac{sin(x)}{\sqrt(x)} \int  \frac{ x}{ sin^2(x)|x|}dx \\ 
&= \frac{sin(x)}{\sqrt(x)} -  \frac{ x cot(x)}{|x|} \\ 
&= \frac{sin(x)}{\sqrt(x)} -  \frac{ x cos(x)}{|x|sin(x)} \\ 
&= \frac{cos(x)}{\sqrt(x)}
\end{align*}$$

The Wronskian matrix :

$$W = \begin{bmatrix}
y_{1} & y_{2} \\
y_{1}'  & y_{2}'
\end{bmatrix}$$

becomes :

$$W = \begin{bmatrix}
 \frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}& \frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{x}} \\
\frac{\sin'(x)}{\sqrt{x}}  & \frac{\cos'(x)}{\sqrt{x}}
\end{bmatrix} \neq 0$$

Thus the determinant is :

\begin{align*} 
W(x) &= \frac{\sin(x)cos'(x)}{\sqrt{x}} - \frac{\sin'(x) cos(x)}{\sqrt{x}} \\
&= - \frac{sin^2(x) + cos^2(x)}{\sqrt(x)} \\
&= - \frac{1}{\sqrt(x)}
\end{align*}

**With Reduction of order**

Given that $$y_1(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}$$ is a solution to the Bessel equation $$x^2y'' + xy' + (x^2 - \frac{1}{4})y = 0$$, i need to find the second linearly independent solution, denoted as $y_2(x)$.

I'll use the method of reduction of order. Assuming $y_2(x) = v(x)y_1(x)$, where $v(x)$ is a function to be determined.

I have:
$$ y_2(x) = v(x)y_1(x) = v(x)\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}} $$

Now, I find $y_2'(x)$ and $y_2''(x)$:
$$ y_2'(x) = v'(x)y_1(x) + v(x)y_1'(x) $$
$$ y_2''(x) = v''(x)y_1(x) + 2v'(x)y_1'(x) + v(x)y_1''(x) $$

Substituting the above into the given differential equation:
$$ x^2y_2'' + xy_2' + (x^2 - \frac{1}{4})y_2 = 0 $$

i have :

$$ x^2(v''(x)y_1(x) + 2v'(x)y_1'(x) + v(x)y_1''(x)) + x(v'(x)y_1(x) + v(x)y_1'(x)) + (x^2 - \frac{1}{4})v(x)y_1(x) = 0 $$

I substitute $y_1(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}$ and its derivatives:
$$ x^2(v''(x)\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}} + 2v'(x)\frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{x}} - v(x)\frac{\sin(x)}{2x\sqrt{x}}) + x(v'(x)\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}} + v(x)\frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{x}}) + (x^2 - \frac{1}{4})v(x)\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}} = 0 $$

Now, i want to choose $v(x)$ such that the terms involving $v(x)$ cancel each other out. I can do this by setting the coefficient of $\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}$ to zero. This gives me the following differential equation for $v(x)$:
$$ x^2(v''(x) + 2v'(x)\frac{1}{x} - v(x)\frac{1}{2x}) + x(v'(x)\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} + v(x)\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}) + (x^2 - \frac{1}{4})v(x) = 0 $$

How I proceed further ? Any help ?

Comment: You didn't differentiate $\dfrac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}$ correctly.

Comment: @CheeHan where? can you be more specific?In which method ?

Comment: You claimed that $y_1' = \frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{x}}$ but you need to use the Product Rule to compute $y_1'$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y_2=\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt x}u$ be a solution. Then
$$ y_2'=\frac{2 x \sin (x) u'(x)+u(x) (2 x \cos (x)-\sin (x))}{2 x^{3/2}}$$
and
$$ y_2''=\frac{u(x) \left(\left(3-4 x^2\right) \sin (x)-4 x \cos (x)\right)+4 x \left(x \sin (x)
   u''(x)+u'(x) (2 x \cos (x)-\sin (x))\right)}{4 x^{5/2}}. $$
Now putting them in the equation gives
$$ x^{3/2}(2\cos(x)u'+\sin(x)u'')=0 $$
which gives
$$ \frac{u''}{u'}=-\frac{2\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}. $$
Integrating both sides gives
$$ u'=\frac{c_1}{\sin^2(x)} $$
from which one has
$$ u=-c_1\cot(x)+c_2. $$
Choose $c_1=-1,c_2=0$ and then $u=\cot(x)$. So the second solution is
$$ y_2=\frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt x}\cot(x)=\frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{x}}. $$

Comment: Sorry, it is a small mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ Rewrite the differential equation using

$$v = \sqrt{x}y \implies \begin{cases} xy' = \sqrt{x}v' - \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} v \\ x^2y'' = \sqrt{x^3}v'' -\sqrt{x}v' + \frac{3}{4\sqrt{x}}v\end{cases}$$

which simplifies the differential equation to

$$x^2y'' + xy' + \left(x^2 - \frac{1}{4}\right)y = \sqrt{x^3}v'' + \sqrt{x^3}v = 0$$

or $$v'' + v =0$$

This is a more easily solvable equation now.